# NullPointerException when trying to read Genre from ID3v1 Tag

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read the Genre Tags from mp3 files using the Beaglebuddy and JaudioTagger libraries, and I get a NullPointerException pointing at:

When using Beaglebuddy its caused by:

```
songs.add(mp3.getMusicType().toString());
```

Or when I use JaudioTagger, its caused by:

```
songs.add(f.getID3v1Tag().getGenre().toString());
```

I guess I'm not using these methods properly, because I'm sure that the genres are set. Can anyone tell how should I get the genres?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using those two lines in the same place, and both are getting an NPE-  chances are good that songs is null, its the only variable accessed in both places.  I recommend breaking that line up into multiple parts, saving the intermediate values, and running under a debugger to see which one is null.

Comment: I've tried as you said, now its pointing at mp3.getMusicType().toString(). So its not the songs array.

Comment: @user1477362 have you tried breaking the line up into multiple parts and inspecting in a debugger to see what part is null?

Answer (score 0):

I have used JAudioTagger 2.0.4 Libary.
A ID3V1 Tag Output:

```
ID3v1Tag         v1Tag  = f.getID3v1Tag();
v1Tag.getFirstGenre();
```

Comment: Please speak proper English, it's very hard to understand

Comment: Not everyone can perfect english :P